# error handlers in MPICH and OpenMPI

Tags: mpi, openmpi, mpich

are there any error handlers implemented in OpenMPI and MPICH other than MPI_ERROR_RETURN and MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL? which implementation is better in handling the errors? 
kindly suggest a link for more information about the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those are the only two error handlers defined by the standard currently.

The [MPI forum](http://www.mpi-forum.org/) is currently working on what will become MPI-3, and error handling and fault tolerance will be an important component of the new standard  (there's a [working group](https://svn.mpi-forum.org/trac/mpi-forum-web/wiki/FaultToleranceWikiPage) dedicated to the topic).  Until that work is complete, however, the only way to get stronger fault tolerance out of MPI is to use earlier, nonstandard, extensions.   [FT-MPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/ftmpi/) was a project that developed a very robust MPI, but unfortuantely it's based on MPI1.2; a very early version of the standard.    There's [MPICH-V](http://mpich-v.lri.fr/), based on MPI2, but that's more checkpoint-restart based.

Along the lines of checkpoint-restart, both [OpenMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=ft) and [MPICH2](http://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/mpich2/index.php/Checkpointing_implementation) have support for [BLCR](https://ftg.lbl.gov/CheckpointRestart/CheckpointRestart.shtml), a transparent checkpoint-restart form of fault tolerance which allows easy rollback to the last checkpoint in case of hardware or network failure.